# Navigating from one stack to another not working. Error -The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Login"} was not handled by any navigator

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

I am getting error when I am trying to navigate from screen named "Fullname" to "Login" screen, its actually a back button I wanted to implement, however, it seems that these 2 screens are in 2 different stacks which might be causing the issue.

Below is my code :

```
function MainApp({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Fullname"
        component={Fullname}
        options={() => <Fullname.navigationOptions />}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function AppContainer() {
  const isLoggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.auth.isLoggedIn);
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator
          initialRouteName="Login"
          screenOptions={{
            headerShown: false,
          }}
        >
          {isLoggedIn ? (
            <Stack.Screen
              name="mainApp"
              component={MainApp}
              options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
          ) : (
            <Stack.Group>
              <Stack.Screen
                name="Login"
                component={Login}
                options={() => <Login.navigationOptions />}
              />
            </Stack.Group>
          )}
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}
```